# Databricks - failing to write from a DataFrame to a Delta location

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks, delta-lake

I wanted to change a column name of a Databricks Delta table.

So I did the following:

```
// Read old table data
val old_data_DF = spark.read.format("delta")
.load("dbfs:/mnt/main/sales")

// Created a new DF with a renamed column
val new_data_DF = old_data_DF
      .withColumnRenamed("column_a", "metric1")
      .select("*")

// Dropped and recereated the Delta files location
dbutils.fs.rm("dbfs:/mnt/main/sales", true)
dbutils.fs.mkdirs("dbfs:/mnt/main/sales")

// Trying to write the new DF to the location
new_data_DF.write
.format("delta")
.partitionBy("sale_date_partition")
.save("dbfs:/mnt/main/sales")
```

Here I'm getting an Error at the last step when writing to Delta:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: dbfs:/mnt/main/sales/sale_date_partition=2019-04-29/part-00000-769.c000.snappy.parquet
A file referenced in the transaction log cannot be found. This occurs when data has been manually deleted from the file system rather than using the table `DELETE` statement
```

Obviously the data was deleted and most likely I've missed something in the above logic. Now the only place that contains the data is the `new_data_DF`. 
Writing to a location like `dbfs:/mnt/main/sales_tmp` also fails

What should I do to write data from `new_data_DF` to a Delta location?

Comment: DataFrames are references and they don't hold any data. You should try writing the data to a different location and then swap the tables.

Answer (score 8):

In general, it is a good idea to avoid using `rm` on Delta tables. Delta's transaction log can prevent eventual consistency issues in most cases, however, when you delete and recreate a table in a very short time, different versions of the transaction log can flicker in and out of existence.

Instead, I'd recommend using the transactional primitives provided by Delta.  For example, to [overwrite the data in a table](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-batch.html#overwrite-using-dataframes) you can:

```
df.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").save("/delta/events")
```

If you have a table that has already been corrupted, you can fix it using [FSCK](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/fsck.html).

Comment: Overwriting doesn't allow renaming of the columns and I'm getting the following error: `AnalysisException: A schema mismatch detected when writing to the Delta table`

Comment: You can use the `overwriteSchema` flag it you want to also change the schema of the table as part of the overwrite.  https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-batch.html#replace-table-schema

Answer (score 6):

You could do that in the following way.

```
// Read old table data
val old_data_DF = spark.read.format("delta")
.load("dbfs:/mnt/main/sales")

// Created a new DF with a renamed column
val new_data_DF = old_data_DF
  .withColumnRenamed("column_a", "metric1")
  .select("*")

// Trying to write the new DF to the location
new_data_DF.write
.format("delta")
.mode("overwrite") // this would overwrite the whole data files
.option("overwriteSchema", "true")  //this is the key line.
.partitionBy("sale_date_partition")
.save("dbfs:/mnt/main/sales")
```

OverWriteSchema option will create new physical files with latest schema that we have updated during transformation.